# Unable to reduce the size of my repo before push

Tags: git, github, garbage-collection

I know this problem is discussed many times on SO but none of the solution I am able to find is helping me.

I am trying to push my repo on Git and I am unable to do so. Because my repo size was 107MB. In my git .gotignore I have:

> *.xcuserstate
>
> project.xcworkspace
>
> xcuserdata
>
> .git/objects
>
> app_data

I have tried

> git gc --auto
>
> git gc --aggressive
>
> git gc --prune

Size was reduce but still it is 100MB. Now what else I can do to reduce the size further?

**Note:** Before cloning this repo, size on githug was 68MB. But after making few changes, it was increased to 107MB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to clean up your *local* repository.

A push to another repository will only transfer your new commits. It will not increase the size of the remote repository by much, unless you added huge files in your commits.

How did you measure the size of your local repository? The repository itself is only kept in the `.git` folder. (If you looked at the whole working tree, you would additionally add all the files in your tree, including any ignored files.)
And even if your `.git` would be large, this would not mean that a push will transfer all of this. It will only tranfer those commits reachable by your pushed branch that are not already available in the remote repository.

Comment: I am pushing into repo for the first time.

Comment: In that case your repository should not be much larger than the files contained in your working tree. - If it really is much larger. There might be a commit adding a huge file and another commit removing that file again. You can use `git rebase -i` to clean up your commits. This should be safe, as you did not publish your repository before.

Comment: There is no tracking information for the current branch.

Comment: before I pushed it, size of .git was 32Kb but now after cloning and a single commit, it is 32MB. Sub directory in .git folder named: objects, possess 31MB.